# Simple way to rectangularize the data in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation, panel-data

I have a panel dataset with dyads that looks something like this

```
nsamp1 <- data.frame("id_1" = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), 
                     "id_2" = c("a","b", "a","b"),
                     "Year" = c(1990, 1991, 1990, 1991), 
                     "Val" = runif(4, min=0, max=100), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#     id_1 id_2 Year    Val
# 1    A    a   1990  59.16656
# 2    A    b   1991  71.03290
# 3    B    a   1990  89.68864
# 4    C    b   1991  36.56359
```

I would like to find an efficient way to rectangularize the data so to create all possible combinations of `id_1`, `id_2` and `year` creating a `nxnxt` dataset

The final data should look something like this:

```
#      id_1 id_2 Year    Val
# 1     A    a   1990  59.16656
# 2     A    b   1990  NA
# 3     A    a   1991  NA
# 4     A    b   1991  71.03290
# 5     B    a   1990  89.68864
# 6     B    b   1990  NA
# 7     B    a   1991  NA
# 8     B    b   1991  NA
# 9     C    a   1990  NA
# 10    C    b   1990  NA
# 11    C    a   1991  NA
# 12    C    b   1991  36.56359
```

I know how to do this in multiple steps. But I am **looking for a single line solution** to clean my code something like the `fillin` function in STATA.

I am aware that there was a package `library(SciencesPo)` that had a rectangularize function, but the package has been deprecated due to numerous bugs and it is no longer available. Also, using the archived version does not work for some reason.

Does anyone know about a simple solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `tidyr::complete(nsamp1, id_1, id_2, Year)`

Comment: Thanks! this is great!